# Loading Data in OLB DB from Flat file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to load data from flat file to OLB database Destination in SSIS, but before loading in Source, I want to convert the data...

The problem is that I don't know how to do it. For example:

```
Data: 1,XYZ,03XX-XXXXXX,street number town number, road city
```

Now, I want to remove `road cite`, after `town number` before loading in a flat file destination.

Comment: I am confused. You don't want road city loaded into OLE DB Destination or Flat File Destination? You said before loading into source in your first line and in the last line you are saying before loading into flat file destination !! What is your source and what is your destination? How do you want your data to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in your text file is coming in as in screenshot1 and you want your output to look like the one in screenshot2 then uncheck the column in which you have your road city data as in screenshot3.

[image: Screenshot of text file]

[image: Screenshot of Desired Output]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived column transformation, and use an expression to create a new column that removes the comma that you want to remove.

Then in your OLE DB destination, map the new column instead of the old one to your destination column.